# iOS Simulator WebApp/Bookmark for URL Scheme testing

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, url-scheme

I'm testing a custom URL scheme in my app, and I'd like to add a homescreen icon that calls that url. Whenever I request my custom URL, it opens my app, and then reverts Safari's address bar to the previously shown URL.

I tried to skirt this issue by editing the properties of another URL, e.g.

1. Open Safari
2. Navigate to http://google.com
3. Tap the action button, and then "Add to home"

But this fails because you can't edit the URL assigned to the homescreen app.

As a fallback, I thought about just having a bookmark to the application, so I tried to bookmark a website and then edit the URL like this:

1. Open Safari
2. Navigate to http://google.com
3. Tap the action button, and then "Bookmark"

but this fails because on the iOS simulator, you can't edit the URL of a bookmark (although you can do this on the device for some reason).

**update:** As tkanzakic points out, you can edit user-added bookmarks, just not the predefined bookmarks

Ideally, I'd like a homescreen app, but would settle for a bookmark instead.

Also, due to firewall restrictions, I can't connect this device to my Apple account, meaning I can't sync my Safari bookmarks either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, figured it out. You can get a webapp on the homescreen pointing to any URL by following these steps:

1. In mobile safari, navigate to any webpage, tap the action button and make a home screen icon for this webpage.
2. Close the simulator
3. Open the directory `/Users/<USERNAME>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Library/WebClips`
4. The webclips folder stores all the homescreen webapps; find the one you just created and open the Info.plist file in a text editor.
5. Edit the keys (such as `URL` and `Title`) as desired.

When you next relaunch the simulator, you homescreen webapp will point to the new URL.

Optionally, you can change the icon.png to change the webapp's icon.

Comment: Seems to be outdated for Xcode 7.1/Simulator 9.1. Can't find where these webclips are stored any more.

Comment: Okay, I found my WebClips in ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{GUID}/data/Library/WebClips.(Xcode 7.1.1/Simulator 9.1)

Answer (score 2):

> As a fallback, I thought about just having a bookmark to the application, so I tried to bookmark a website and then edit the URL like this:
>
> 1. Open Safari
> 2. Navigate to http://google.com
> 3. Tap the action button, and then "Bookmark"
>
> but this fails because on the iOS simulator, you can't edit the URL of a bookmark (although you can do this on the device for some reason).

That is not true, it is possible to change the URL a bookmark, check [this article](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/30/view-source-safari-ipad-iphone/) to see how you can do it. I have done this on the Simulator and on a Device.

Comment: Did you actually try this? The URL field is disabled (tested in iPhone and iPad 5 & 6 simulator)

Comment: yes, it can't be done with google, but it is possible with another web site, I don't know why

Comment: You're right. You can edit a user-added bookmark, just not one of the predetermined bookmarks. If nobody can suggest a way to get a homescreen app, this will be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a small app (using Xcode) that opens the URL in its application delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [application openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myappscheme://whatever/"]];
}
```

Note that I'm using `applicationDidBecomeActive:` instead of `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` to make the launcher app work after it has been launched before.

Alternatively you could set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` in the Info.plist to force termination.